# Sprites appear blue using cocos 2d-iphone, but only in the simulator

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, cocos2d-iphone

I'm running this sample code located here:

http://monoclestudios.com/cocos2d_whitepaper.html

using cocos 2d-iphone 0.7.2, and the sprites are being drawn coloured blue. But this is only happening on the simulator. On an actual device, everything looks fine.

Has anyone else run into this problem?

Comment: I've had this error when running the iPhone SDK on a non-intel mac. It's a 'bug' in the simulator with OpenGL ES that only occurs on some G4 and G5 macs, which are not officially supported by apple as an iPhone development platform.

As others have said, if it works on the device, that's all that really matters. But this particular issue should go away if you try running the simulator on an intel mac.

Comment: Great answer, I didn't consider that it might have something to do with the architecture, but yes it is an iBook G4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the simulator isn't identical to the physical iPhone. I haven't encountered this particular bug, but I did have issues with sounds. Wouldn't play on the simulator but worked fine on the device. If you're only having problems on the simulator I'd suggest ignoring the bug and moving forward. The simulator is just for convenience after all.

Checkout #cocos2d-iphone on freenode if you have more questions like this.

Answer (score 2):

**Don't test** OpenGL ES **on the simulator**. It just isn't the same. The simulator renders slightly differently. **Since cocos2d-iPhone is heavily based on OpenGL ES, your only choice is to test on the device!**